# disable shift ability to upper/lower case letters in a c++ application

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a simulation of an infantry in c++ with Vega Prime.

I use the WASD keys for movement and shift for running.

when I press w and then press shift - when i release w it became a capital W so the event for the release w does't happen (because the shift turn the w to W...).

Now, there is no option to handle the two keys (w and W) because some reason that is not important.

All I want to do is to disable the SHIFT KEY ability in the application to upper/lower letters.

how can I do that?

Comment: No, that isn't the way the Windows API works. Show us the code for your event handler and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each character read to uppercase:

```
#include <cctype>
handleInput(toupper(c))
```